# C# How To Update Entity Model Connection String

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my first WinForm application using the Entity Framework and I have to be able to update the connection string for the entity model I created on the fly and in my app.config file I have the following connectionString:

```
<add name="NCIPEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NCIPModel.csdl|res://*/NCIPModel.ssdl|res://*/NCIPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Test\NCIP\NCIP.db3&quot;;pooling=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is what I wrote to update the string on the fly, it doesn't throw any errors when it runs but it also doesn't save the new connection string back to the app.config file.

```
private void UpdateEntityConnection()
    {
        StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
        Sb.Append(@"metadata=res://*/NCIPModel.csdl|res://*/NCIPModel.ssdl|res://*/NCIPModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider""");
        Sb.Append("connection string='data source=" + Settings.Default.Directory + "\\NCIP.db3;pooling=True'");

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NCIPEntities"].ConnectionString = Sb.ToString();

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong because I don't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you know you can do this:

```
var connstr = GetConnectionString();

using (NCIPEntities ctx = new NCIPEntities(connstr))
{
    ...
}
```

I.e. the Entity Framework doesn't have to get the connection string from the App.Config.

Anyway knowing this might change your approach/requirements a little?

Hope this helps

Alex

PS: you might want to check out my [Tip 45](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/11/29/tip-45-how-to-swap-ef-metadata-at-runtime.aspx) for more info.
I have a [whole series of Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx) too

Comment: Oh I was under the impression this had to come from the app config file.  If this is not the case I can then store the string as a User Setting and then use that instead of the app.config?

Comment: Absolutely, I had a felling you didn't know this.

Comment: Is there any way to set one time connection string. i.e. when i call to db then every time i set connection string.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) instead of trying to rewrite it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [article here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030907.asp) will help you but ...

From article ... emphasis mine

> So here's my take on a convenient
>   little class that allows you to either
>   modify, add or delete any appSettings
>   element, in either your Executable,
>   Console or ASP.NET web application at
>   runtime, on the fly. Bear in mind of
>   course, that if you modify a
>   web.config on a running ASP.NET app,
>   the ASP.NET worker process will
>   recycle. **Users currently using your
>   app aren't exactly guaranteed to have
>   a fun experience when this happens...**

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

So I have to initialise NCIPEntities in application start event itself. Right?

But since I to get the database name from the database every time my application restarts, is there a way I can modify the EntityConnectionString and save it back to config file. Just like the SqlConnectionString.InitialCatalog property.