# Get the connection string for Entity Framework using the POCO template

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, app-config

I use Entity Framework and I need to get my connection string so I can construct a context.

I am using the POCO template.  My context object has:

```
string ConnectionString = "name=MyAppConfigConnectionStringPropertyHere"
```

So when I try to just construct my context it says

> "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid"

I saw in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888948/c-how-to-update-entity-model-connection-string/1889199#1889199) that indicated that there is a GetConnectionString() method.  But googling has not lead me to the reference I need to add to get that method (it is not in my project by default).

So, I can't think that I am the first one who wants to get a connection string for entity framework using the POCO templates.  How have others done this?  I guess I can just read in the whole app.config file and parse it out.  But it seems like it should not be that hard.

Any hints would be great!

Answer (score 28):

For entity framework 6.0, following code gives current ConnectionString.

```
context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 9):

For people not using EF 4.1 here is the easiest way to do it that I know of:

```
using System.Data.EntityClient;

public static string GetConnectionString(ObjectContext context)
{
    return ((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I get the DB connection like this

```
 var connection = (SqlConnection)_context.Database.Connection;
```

Then from connection you get the `ConnectionString`  and other info you need

Comment: This does not seem to work if the connection string contains a password (password is not in the string).

Answer (score 2):

For EF Core, use:

```
context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a connectionString-element present in the web.config that the specified name used on the context:

```
<configuration>
     <connectionStrings>
          <add name="MyAppConfigConnectionStringPropertyHere"
               providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
               connectionString="Data Source...." />
     </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I am using a entity framework on a class library project.  I don't have a web.config.  All the connection string stuff is in App.confg and looks more like this: `connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDataModel.csdl|....`  The provider name is `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

Comment: Does this connectionString has a name-attribute? It should match the actual connection-string passed to the context, you've mentioned.

Comment: Yes there is a name property. It is the same as the part after `name=` in the code for the property for the connection string.  I just don't know how to use that to load the actual connection string from App.config and use it in the code.  I tried `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyAppConfigConnectionStringPropertyHere"].ConnectionString` and it fails.  When I dig into the connection strings list (using the debugger) my connection string is not in there.  (it only has a connection to my localhost sql server).

Comment: Turns out that I had the data in the wrong app.config.  My class library that held my entities was being run by a different project that was a WCF Service Library.  Once I moved the connection string to that app.config it all worked great.